# Filename from string(path) without file exist

Tags: c#, string, filenames

I am trying to get a file name out of a string, but it is possible the file does not exist (yet) when trying to get the file name.
So as far as i know, i can not use the Path.GetFileName Method, or can i somehow still use this method without the file actually existing?

Example of the string: `C:\cSharp\test\001.txt`

The length of the file name can variate.
What would be the best approach to try to get the file name? through regular expressions? maybe some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* use the `Path` methods even if the file doesn't exist. Actually those [`Path` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are just string methods. So this works:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"C:\cSharp\test\001.txt"); //001.txt
```